# How to speed up this Regular Expression in .Replace function?

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have 4.5 million rows to process, so I need to speed this up so bad. 
I don't understand how regex works pretty well, so other answers are so hard for me to understand.

I have a column that contains **ID**s, e.g.:

> ELI-123456789

This numeric part of this ID is contained in this string in a columnm **bk_name** started with a "@":

> AAAAA@123456789_BBBBB;CCCCC;

Now my goal is to change that string into this string, throw the ID at the end, started with a "#", save it in **new_name**:

> AAAAA_BBBBB;CCCCC;#123456789

Here's what I tried:

1. Take the **ID** and replace "ELI-" with "@", save as **ID2**:

`df["ID2"] = df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "@")`

2. Find **ID2** in the string of **bk_name** and replace it with "":

`df["new_name"] = df["bk_name"].replace(regex = r'(?i)' + df["ID2"].astype(str), value = "")`

3. Take the **ID** again, replace "ELI-" with "#", add it at the end of the string of **new_name**:

`df["new_name"] = df["new_name"] + df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "#")`

Now the problem is that step 2 is the line that takes most of the time, it took 6.5 second to process 6700 rows.
But now I have 4.6 millions rows to process, it's been 7 hours and it's still running and I have no idea why.

In my opinions, regex slows down my code. But I have no deeper understanding.
So thanks for your help in advance, any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: why not `df["ID2"].astype(str)` as `df["ID2"].str`? Instead of casting, fetching a parameter. That's a lot faster. But it's nothing to do with regex.

Comment: @samthegolden Then I have an error: TypeError: must be str, not StringMethods. I don't quite understand that, what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @samthegolden  Just solved it with little help from my friend ! See my own answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say that if you know that the ID part is always `ELI-` followed by a number and that this number is always behind the `@` at the beginning then I would consider not reading the ID at step 1. Directly work at step 2 with this regular expression and replacement:

https://regex101.com/r/QBQB7E/1

You should be able to create the content of your new field just with one single assignement with the result of the substitution of the old field. The idea to 
speed up things is to avoid having 4-5 lines of code to do the operation of
getting the id, searching it and then recomposing the result. The regular 
expression and the substitution pattern can do all that in one single operation.

You can generate some Python code directly from Regex101 so that you can integrate it to create your `new_name` field's content.

**Explanation**

`^(.*?)@(\d+)(.*)$` is the regular expression

- `^` means "starting with".
- `$` means "ending with".
- `()` is to capture a group and create a variable that we can then use
  in the replacement pattern. `\1` for the first matching group, `\2` for
  the second, etc.
- `.*?` matches any character between zero and unlimited times, as few times
  as possible, expanding as needed (lazy).
- `@` matches the character @ literally (case sensitive).
- `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9]) one or more times.
- `.*` matches any character between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

The replacement string is `\1\3#\2`, so it takes the first matching group 
followed by the last one and then adds a `#` followed by the second matching 
group, which is your id.

In terms of speed of the regex itself, it could also be changed a little bit
to find a faster version of it, depending how it's written.

Second version:

- `^([^@]+)@(\d+)(.*)$` where I replaced `.*?` by `[^@]+` meaning find any
  character which is not `@` one or more times.
- Solution here: https://regex101.com/r/QBQB7E/3

Tested the code and I got it in about 4 seconds...

```py
import timeit

code_to_test = """
import re

regex = r"^([^@]+)@(\d+)(.*)$"
subst = "\\1\\3#\\2"

df = {
    "ID": "ELI-123456789",
    "bk_name": "AAAAA@123456789_BBBBB;CCCCC;"
}

df["new_name"] = re.sub(regex, subst, df["bk_name"])
"""

elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=4600000)
print(elapsed_time)
```

I really think that if you code runs in 7 hours, it's probably somewhere else
where the problem is. The regex engine doesn't seem much slower than doing 
manual search/replace operations.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried the code in the code generator and I wrote this:
`regex = r"^(.*?)@(\d+)(.*)$"`

`subst = "\\1\\3#\\2"`

`result = re.sub(regex, subst, df["ID"], 0, re.MULTILINE)`

But I have: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.
It's strange because df["ID"] is a string in column **ID** in **df**.

Sorry for the bad format of the comment I don't know how to clean that up...

Comment: @g.on I don't know what your problem is. I'll let you solve it. I've edited my answer and put the regex substitution method and it runs in approximatively 4 seconds on my computer. I suppose the slow part is somewhere else. Good research!

Comment: Just solved it with little help from my friend !  See my own answer

Answer (score 0):

So, your approach wasn't that bad.

I recommend you look into the functions docs before using them. [replace](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/replace.html) takes no keyword arguments.

Regarding step 2, don't use a regex just for replacing a string with another string (`""` in this case).

```
df = {};
df['ID'] = 'ELI-123456789'; df['bk_name'] = 'AAAAA@123456789_BBBBB;CCCCC;';
print(df)

# Take the ID and replace "ELI-" with "@", save as ID2:

# df["ID2"] = df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "@")
df["ID2"] = df["ID"].replace("ELI-", "@")
print(df)

# Find ID2 in the string of bk_name and replace it with "":

# df["new_name"] = df["bk_name"].replace(regex = r'(?i)' + df["ID2"].astype(str), value = "")
df["new_name"] = df["bk_name"].replace(df["ID2"], "")
print(df)

# Take the ID again, replace "ELI-" with "#", add it at the end of the string of new_name:

# df["new_name"] = df["new_name"] + df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "#") 
df["new_name"] = df["new_name"] + df["ID"].replace("ELI-", "#") 
print(df)
```

Hope it helps

EDIT:

Are you sure it's this piece of code the one slowing down your project? Have you tried to isolate it and see how long it actually takes to execute?

Try this:

```
import timeit
code_to_test = """
df = {};
df['ID'] = 'ELI-123456789'; df['bk_name'] = 'AAAAA@123456789_BBBBB;CCCCC;';
df["new_name"] = df['bk_name'].replace('@' + df['ID'][4:],'') + '#' + df['ID'][4:] # <----- ONE LINER
# print(df['new_name'])
"""
elapsed_time = timeit.timeit(code_to_test, number=4600000)
print(elapsed_time)
```

I shortened it to a one-liner which ONLY WORKS IF:

- *ELI-* (or a 4-character string) is always the string to be replaced
- *@* is always the character to be removed and *#* is always the one to be added

At least in the laptop I'm coding this, it always executes the code 4600000 times in under 4 secs

Comment: I think he is working in Python, not in PHP. But anyway, there's far to much operations. All that can be done in one single assignement with the help of a single regexp. We don't need to get the ID from the other field as we can find it directly in his `bk_name` field.

Comment: @Scaramouche Thanks! It makes sense. I tried your line but the new line you wrote me takes 8.8 seconds. So it's even longer than my line.

Comment: @g.on, sorry, what do you mean by new line? also, remember to remove all the prints, of course. and check my edit

Comment: @Scaramouche I mean the line you wrote took 8.8 seconds and mine 6.5.  I have millions of rows to process, is there still a way to speed that up? And yes I've checked the time every line takes and it's this line that slow down my code :)

Comment: Hey @Scaramouche  I just found that your 'one liner' doesn't actually replace anything, I have no idea why. I got AAAAA@123456789_BBBBB;CCCCC;#ELI-123456789

Comment: @Scaramouche Just solved it with little help of my friend !  See my own answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what caused the problem but I solved it.

The only thing I changed is in step 2. I used apply/lambda function and it suddenly works and I have no idea why.

1. Take the **ID** and replace "ELI-" with "@", save as **ID2**:

`df["ID2"] = df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "@")`

2. Find **ID2** in the string of **bk_name** and replace it with "":

`df["new_name"] = df[["bk_name", "ID2"]].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x["bk_name"].replace(x["ID2"], ""), axis=1)`

3. Take the **ID** again, replace "ELI-" with "#", add it at the end of the string of **new_name**:

`df["new_name"] = df["new_name"] + df["ID"].str.replace("ELI-", "#")`

Comment: @samthegolden Just edited it! I made a editing mistake